Unity. Звуковое сопровождение
Unity. Я реализовал появление звуков при нажатии на определённые кнопки, но если я нажимаю 2 или более кнопки одновременно, то звук проигрывается только 1. Пример - У меня есть звуки ходьбы которые появляются при нажатии на wasd, и так же стрельба на кнопку мыши, и в моём случае, когда я хожу, и одновременно пытаюсь стрелять, воспроизводятся только звуки ходьбы, спасибо всем заранее!
